# Retrieve Permissions list

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to retrieve the permissions of the apps in my device.

The weird thing is, for some apps I do get results, and in some of them I can't retrieve any permissions.

Maybe in order to get the permissions list of an app, the app has to set some specific flag? Because if I try to get the permission list of my app in this way:

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
PermissionInfo[] z=p.getPackageInfo("com.test.myapp",PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).permissions);
```

`z` is `null`, but for some apps (system apps, etc..) I do get some list.

Any idea?

Thanks, moshik.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as i discovered it, the PermissionInfo contains only non-default permissions ( other than android.Manifest.permission.* ).

The only way ( i found ) is to manually check the android.Manifest.permission.* via

```
PackageManager.checkPermission(String permName, String pkgName);
```

Comment: Ive also couldnt find farther information about this issue,
thanks for helping!