# Mic works without permission, but doesn't when revoking Google's Mic permission

Tags: android, permissions, microphone

I am using [this SearchView library](https://github.com/lapism/SearchView) in my app. The `RECORD_AUDIO` permission is not part of my application but I can still use the voice search feature without being prompted for permission. However, if I disable the **Google** app's **Microphone** permission, the feature doesn't work. It doesn't crash or ask for permission, it just kind of stutters.

So my questions are:

1. How is my app using the Google app's permissions like this?
2. How can I handle a user that has disabled the **Google** app's **Microphone** permission?

---

### Some info:

In the example app's [AndroidManifest](https://github.com/lapism/SearchView/blob/master/sample/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission is listed, but I did not list it in mine.

I have checked both:

- `/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`
- `/app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt`

Neither of the files have any mention of a `RECORD_AUDIO` permission. My application's permissions settings do not list **Microphone** as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [the source code](https://github.com/lapism/SearchView/blob/master/searchview/src/main/java/com/lapism/searchview/SearchView.java#L1040), it uses the [RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH) Intent, which is handled by the Google app. Therefore it is the Google app that is doing voice recognition (and hence, requires the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission), not your app.

Comment: Is there a way to know if another app's permissions have been granted?

Comment: This information made me find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353773/retrieve-permissions-list) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386823/how-to-get-manifest-permissions-of-any-installed-android-app). I will mark as answered when I test in the morning.

Comment: Yep, you'll want to use [checkPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))  to check if the permission is granted with the package name gotten from the results of [queryIntentActivities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) (as it might not always be the Google app).